# Importing methods in Java

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm a beginner of Java and I was learning from murach's book how to validate input data. I've done by myself a simple restaurant menù , but when I import a method to validate data from a utility class made by me, somehow it doesn't work! (stacktrace in the end of the thread).

But if i set it into the menù class it just works (only for menùid but it has to go also for "spesa"), so it must be something wrong into importing.. or maybe I've done things the wrong way.

Utility class below :

```
   class utilità {
    protected static int getint (Scanner sc){
        int t = 0;
        boolean check = false;
            while (check == false) {
                if (sc.hasNextInt())
                {
                    t = sc.nextInt();
                    check = true;
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println("Errore! Si prega di inserire un numero 
    intero.");
                } sc.nextLine();
            } return t;
    }
    }
   //  My menù class :
     protected static void Menù(){
       int menùid;
       System.out.println("Benvenuto nel menù del ristorante!");
       System.out.println("Inserire 0 per uscire :");
       System.out.println("Inserire 1 per ricevere un suggerimento per 
    l'ordinazione :");  
        menùid = utilità.getint(data);
            switch (menùid){
                case 1 :
                    Decidi();
                               System.out.println("Ottima scelta!");
                    break;
                case 0 :
                                System.out.println("Arrivederci e grazie!");
                    break;
            }
       } } <code>
My import : import menùautomatizzato.utilità; import java.util.*;
My main class : mainclass.java (there's only the main method where i use the Menù function)


//Method decidi()
protected static void Decidi () {
       System.out.println("Inserire quanto si pensa di spendere");
       double spesa = data.nextDouble();
       if (spesa >= 50)
           System.out.println("Il ristorante suggerisce : Primo , secondo e contorno per 2 persone");
       else if (spesa <= 50)
           System.out.println("Il ristorante suggerisce : Primo e contorno per 2 persone");
       else if (spesa < 25)
           System.out.println("Il ristorante suggerisce : Primo e contorno per 1 persona");          
   }
```

The code text is shown in Italian because that's my language.

The error that occurs when it's selected the option 1 from the Menù and the user enters a letter instead of a number, and getint is supposed to handle this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864) at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Scanner.java:2413)
    at menùautomatizzato.MenùAutomatizzato.Decidi(MenùAutomatizzato.java:12)
    at menùautomatizzato.MenùAutomatizzato.Menù(MenùAutomatizzato.java:28)
    at menùautomatizzato.mainclass.main(mainclass.java:10)
Java Result: 1
```

I was a little bit dumb, thanks for JBnizet that made me realize the fix in the comments, fix :

```
 protected static double getdouble(Scanner sc){
        double d = 0;
        boolean check = false;
            while (check == false) {
                if (sc.hasNextDouble())
                {
                    d = sc.nextDouble();
                    check = true;
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println("Errore! Si prega di inserire un numero.");
                } sc.nextLine();
            } return d;
    }
```

Comment: Please explain ["doesn't work"](https://web.archive.org/web/20180124130721/http://importblogkit.com/2015/07/does-not-work/). Are you getting compilation error, runtime exception or results different from what you expect?

Comment: And if you get an error (compilation or runtime), then read it first, and then post it, completely and exactly.

Comment: Sorry, i was doing so much copy&paste that i missed the most important section, it should be there now!

Comment: What do you mean? The first attempt i've done is similar to the book, i just wrote the validate data code all toghether with the rest and it was working, i've missed something when i re-wrote it?

Comment: So, the error happens when the user selects the first option. In that case, the method Decidi is being called. That's confirmed by the stack trace, which shows that the problem happens at line 12 of MenùAutomatizzato.java, inside the Decidi method. But you haven't posted that method.

Comment: I mean if you set it into the class and then provide a letter instead of a number it doesn't just work. It throws the same exception. So it just works exactly the same way as if you include it in the menu class.

Comment: OK, so now you know that calling data.nextDouble(), it tells you that the next token is not a double. So your assumptions on what `data` contains are wrong. But we have no idea of what `data` is, how you defined it, and what it's supposed to contain.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Calling a user a "liar" is unkind and against the side's [Code of Conduct](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct).

Comment: Data is used in decidi() to insert a value in euros that is analyzed into an if and it gives a response based on how much euros the user is willing to spend at the restaurant, i hope this explains it

Comment: *But if i set it into the menù class it just works* Just do that then.

Comment: No, it doesn't. Post the relevant code. When trying to find a bug in the code, the code matters. A lot.

Comment: JBnizet just made me realize that the code works for data, if i enter "a" instead of 25 euros for example the exception is handled! But i want the method to work for menùid too, if that's possible.. Should i make another method but instead of getint a getdouble to fix this?

Comment: sorry elliot, i see what you want to point out, but the program should work as a teaching method to learn how to be as more efficient as possible (for begginers ofc) and so it says "use more classes for the methods..." and so on.. so i have to split things up

Comment: anyhow i have explained myself the wrong way, data and menù id work fine it's "spesa" that throws an error, and i have to handle that one, is it fine to make just another method to check a double value this time ?

Comment: I'm not sure of what you're asking. All I can say is that your method calls data.getDouble(), and that if the next token in data is not a Double, then of course, as documented, that will throw an exception. So if you want to support other data types, you need to change the code of that method to handle the other types of data the way you want to.

Comment: thanks JBNizet , i'm aware that i was explaining myself completely wrong sorry about that, and yes i need to add code in the utility class to handle the exception for the double data this time. Thanks again!